# (Errno 30: Read-only file system) when creating python virtualenv in shared folder

Tags: python, readonly, virtualenv

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 trying to create a python virtual enviroment (named "my_virtualenv") inside my VBOX shared folder with the idea to use this python interpreter in pycharm from my Windows host. (Just to see if its possible)

The shared folder works correctly, I can create/manipulate files from both host and guest. I created the folder from VBOX client selecting only "auto-mount" and "make permanent" (did not select "read-only").

When I run `virtualenv my_virtualenv` after a few seconds I get the following:

```
root@luis-VirtualBox:/media/sf_KUBUNTU/ENV# virtualenv my_virtualenv
New python executable in /media/sf_KUBUNTU/ENV/my_virtualenv/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1370, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
```

As you can see I tried running the command from root without success, I guess it has something to do with permissions but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: `errno 30` is `Read-only file system`.  It also says `Read-only file system` in the log you posted. Is your file system read-only?

Comment: Correct, I should have been clearer, I add it to title.

Comment: it seems like a virtualbox issue https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/209